# Computing spectral gap of p-laplacian, p > 2

Tags: clustering

I'm looking for code allowing computation of the spectral gap of a graph p-laplacian with p > 2, i.e. the second largest eigenvalue. See http://www.ml.uni-saarland.de/code/pSpectralClustering/pSpectralClustering.htm for the concept (the code provided there only works for p \le 2). Alternatively, I'd like to know if this nonlinear optimization can be performed using some off-the-shelf methods, like straightforward gradient descent etc.